# struts 2.0 allow HTML in label of s:checkbox

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I have a checkbox for agreeing to the terms and conditions of a contenst, and the user wants the terms linked in the label. I've attempted to do something like this:

```
<s:checkbox name="iagree" fieldValue="true" label="By entering, I acknowledge that I have read, understand, and agree to the 
<a href='/rules.pdf'>Official Rules</a>, <a href='/about-us/terms-of-use/'>Terms of Use</a>, and <a href='/about-us/privacy-policy/'>Privacy Policy</a>."/>
```

Unfortunately, the JSP is escaping my markup, and so you actually see the brackets, tags, etc. Is there an attribute I can add to make sure that the HTML is actually used as HTML?

Curiously, I have a struts radio group, and it is allowing markup just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use HTML `<label>` tag and place checkbox along with text and links inside it. And use `simple` theme for the `<s:checkbox>` tag.

```
<label>
  <s:checkbox name="iagree" fieldValue="true" theme="simple"/>
  By entering, I acknowledge that I have read, understand, and agree to the 
  <a href='/rules.pdf'>Official Rules</a>, 
  <a href='/about-us/terms-of-use/'>Terms of Use</a>, 
  and <a href='/about-us/privacy-policy/'>Privacy Policy</a>.
</label>
```